# how do I store the output of a cut command into a variable

Tags: unix

I want to store something like this in a variable but it's not working. `hello.txt` has a line inside the file that I want to cut and store into the variable list but I don't know how.

```
list=$(echo "hello.txt" | cut -f2 -d '/')
```

This is for unix/shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command isn't checking the **contents** of *hello.txt*, but only the **name** "hello.txt" itself. Add `xargs` so that the final command is:

`list=$(echo "hello.txt" | xargs cut -f2 -d '/')`

As @Kusalananda points out, you can also simplify this further:

`list=$( cut -f2 -d/ hello.txt )`

Comment: Would be easier with `list=$( cut -f2 -d '/' hello.txt )`